# Getting only matching item from an array using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I would like mongodb to only return a matching item from an array. For some reason it returns the complete document and not just the item.

My data :

```
{
    "car_type": "fiat",
    "car_parts": [
        {"part_name": "door", "part_color": "blue"},
        {"part_name": "roof", "part_color": "purple"}
    ]
},
{
    "car_type": "ferrari",
    "car_parts": [
        {"part_name": "door", "part_color": "red"},
        {"part_name": "wheels", "part_color": "yellow"}
    ]
},
```

If I do

```
collection.find_one(filter={"car_type": "fiat", "car_parts": {"$elemMatch": {"part_color": "blue"}}})
```

I get the complete document :

```
{
    "car_type": "fiat",
    "car_parts": [
        {"part_name": "door", "part_color": "blue"},
        {"part_name": "roof", "part_color": "purple"}
    ]
}
```

What I would like instead is the matching item from the array

```
{"part_name": "door", "part_color": "blue"}
```

There is plenty documentation about matching an item from an array but none about getting only the matching item instead of getting the whole doc. I really don't want to get all of the array's content. I just need the matching item, that's all...

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Solved it...

It's kind of a duplicate of this very old question [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3985214/5512455)

The best approch to get only the item(s) that match and not the full document is by using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#-filter--aggregation-) which is in my opinion very badly registered by search engines as I never stumble upon it...

```
collection.aggregate([{"$match": {"car_type": "ferrari"}},
        {"$project": {
            "car_parts": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$car_parts",
                    "as": "car_part",
                    "cond": {"$eq": ["$$car_part.part_color", "red"]}
                }
            }
        }}
        ])
```

*Note that "$$" is normal.

The value of "as" can be anything but should preferably be the singular of what you are searching for and must then be used inside the "cond" expression.*

This will return something like this :

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId('61d80660961da1a184cb8c85'),
    "car_parts": [
      {"part_name": "door", "part_color": "red"}
    ]
  }
]
```

The outer array is useless but it's easy to get rid of it.
Also remember that agregations don't return a dict but a cursor.
The easiest way to print its content is by using `list`

```
print(str(list(req_result)))
```